# Slow PHP response times from Apache Benchmark

Tags: apache-2.2, benchmark, mpm-prefork

I have a VPS running Apache (prefork mpm) with 1gb RAM and 2 x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 0 @ 2.00GHz.

I setup 2 test files to run through Apache Benchmark:
htmltest.html (basic HTML file which just displays some text)
phptest.php (a completely blank php file)

I ran the following Apache Benchmark command for each:
ab -k -n 1000 -c 70 THE-TEST-URL

The results were:

**htmltest.html**

```
Concurrency Level:      70
Time taken for tests:   5.374 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Keep-Alive requests:    992
Total transferred:      374658 bytes
HTML transferred:       134000 bytes
Requests per second:    186.10 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       376.145 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       5.374 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          68.09 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    1   5.5      0      48
Processing:    17   94 454.3     50    5173
Waiting:       17   93 454.3     50    5173
Total:         17   94 458.8     50    5221
```

---

**phptest.php**

```
Concurrency Level:      70
Time taken for tests:   125.159 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Keep-Alive requests:    997
Total transferred:      196815 bytes
HTML transferred:       0 bytes
Requests per second:    7.99 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       8761.120 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       125.159 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          1.54 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   4.0      0      58
Processing:  1003 1244  84.7   1235    2953
Waiting:      997 1244  84.9   1235    2953
Total:       1029 1244  85.8   1235    3012
```

---

Something has to be wrong here because the HTML file took only 5 seconds to complete the test and the blank PHP file took a whole 2 minutes to do the exact same test.

Is there a specific config file I should be looking at to fix the problem here?

Comment: What have you checked so far?

Comment: I've checked my PHP config which is:
memory_limit = 64M, max_execution_time = 30, max_input_time = 60. I'm using PHP 5 Handler suphp with Apache suEXEC turned on.